# lambda with custom authorizer works on test with console but not with postman

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless, lambda-authorizer

I have a lambda function that works when testing on the AWS console. But once I test on Postman it gives me the following response

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I basically have a Authorization on the header with a Bearer token like so

```
Bearer <my token>
```

The body is empty as it's only a Get endpoint. Not sure what I'm missing on my request from postman. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you console log the event in the authorizer lambda ? 
(And of course, are you sure you rightly set the authorization header in postman?)

Comment: @BTL , yeah made sure (like this https://imgur.com/a/FXJls3T). On the images, you'll see the results on the dashboard and how I would add the token on postman, you wont see any console log output.

Comment: Did you redeploy the API after you've tested it in the console? Take a read here and let me know https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-protect-apis-with-jwt-and-api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-1110ff035df1#2e6d

Comment: If its protected by an api token the header is x-api-key. Another common reason for that error is that you have the URL typed in wrong. (check the trailing slash)

Comment: figured it out, @BAD_SEED , that's the tutorial I was trying to follow whe I first encountered this, incredible how I missed that part on the Authorization header.

Comment: @gdubs I am facing the same issue, but in my case protocol type is HTTP and not REST. Do you know how we can fix this with HTTP as protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally. If you're posting Authorization with a setup where you have "Authorization" as the token source and blank Token Validation (like below), you don't add the word "Bearer" on postman. Still have to research why that is and how that works (as i dont understand). Any help on where to look at as to why when you post with an Authorization header some apis require "Bearer" but this one does not.

[image]

Comment: I'm the author of that article. Please make a lot of claps if you liked. :)
The `Bearer` is needed when you offer more authentication mechanism  (like `Basic` or `Digest`).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your custom authorizer in API Gateway is properly configured (you can go to authorizers and test it from there too). Then make sure that the endpoint that calls that lambda has your custom authorizer set. Finally if you are just developing a few lambdas, creating them using the aws console it's fine, but maybe it would be better for you to use a serverless deployment framework like https://serverless.com/ or SAM. I have found that even for small projects they let you have more control over what you do in an easy way, and the learning curve it's not that hard. 
Hope you fix it, and have a great day.